# Blocking particular website for specific thinclients on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, squid, system-administration

We have server which is connected with more than thin client machine. I have tried to block the websites ( facebook, orkut,twitter ) for all the users. it works fine for me. But , I want to block for particular user  ( thinclient ) or by the way of IP address of machine. How can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

squid is a proxy that is allow reduce the internet bandwidth and block the websites in linux os
For block a particular website use this command 
1. vi /etc/squid/squid.conf  /* for editing this file
2. **Enter following command**
     acl bad(name of the variable) url_regex [http://www.google.com (if you want to block        Google.com)
    http_access deny  bad(variable name)
    http_access allow all
3. change the port number of the proxy that used in your web browser to 3128

Answer (score 0):

iptables is tool that used in Linux for protecting the system from ip or network
if you want to block a particular ip or network just use this command

1. If u want to block a particular ip like 192.168.0.5 then use this command

   `iptables -t filter -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.5 -j REJECT`
2. From a network [network id is 192.168.0.0]

   `iptables -t filter -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0 -j REJECT`

Comment: Actually  I want to block particular web address  from my specific machines (  thin clients )

Comment: if u want to block particular ip/wed address use this command iptables -A OUTPUT -d www. goggle.com -j DROP